# Reassembling chunks of a binary file in Perl in a multithreaded script

Tags: multithreading, perl

I'm trying to break a binary file into chunks for a multipart upload and then have them reassembled correctly. I'm using threads to try to speed up transfers. The result hasn't validated using `md5sum` so I decided to try to just to reassemble it locally and see what happens. The local result comes out ok with a small text file, but not a large binary file, when multithreaded. It works either way when single threaded.

Here's a simple (admittedly inefficient) implementation of a single threaded version that works:

```
use strict;
use POSIX;

my $file = 'test.txt';
my $chunkSize = 3;
my $size = -s $file;
my $parts = ceil($size / $chunkSize);

my %output;
open(my $fileHandle, '<', $file) or die("Error reading file, stopped");
binmode($fileHandle);

for (my $i = 0; $i < $parts; $i++) {
    my $chunk;
    my $offset = $i * $chunkSize;

    seek ($fileHandle, $offset, 0);

    if ($chunkSize > $size) {
        $chunkSize = $size;
    }
    elsif (($chunkSize + $offset) > $size) {
        $chunkSize = $size - $offset;
    }

    my $length = read($fileHandle, $chunk, $chunkSize); 
    say STDERR "Chunk size for $i: " . $chunkSize . "(" . ($chunkSize + $offset) . "/$size) starting at " . $offset .": ";# . $chunk;

    $output{ $i } = $chunk;
}

close($fileHandle); 

open(my $fileHandle, '>', $file . '.comp') or die("Error reading file, stopped");
binmode($fileHandle);

for (1...$parts) {
    print $fileHandle $output{ $_ };
}

close ($fileHandle);
```

Here's the multithreaded version that does not:

```
use strict;
use POSIX;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;

my $file = '/backup/2022-12-13/accounts/test.tar.gz';

my $chunkSize = 500 * 1024 * 1024;
#Or my $chunkSize = 3; when using it with the smaller text test file.
my $size = -s $file;
my $parts = ceil($size / $chunkSize);

my %output :shared;

my @queueData;
for (0...$parts) { push (@queueData, $_); }

my $overallProgress :shared;
my $queue = Thread::Queue->new(@queueData);

open(my $fileHandle, '<', $file) or die("Error reading file, stopped");
binmode($fileHandle);

my @threads;
for(1..4) {
    push @threads, threads->create( sub {

        while( my $i = $queue->dequeue_nb ) {
            my $chunk;
            my $offset = ($i - 1) * $chunkSize;

            seek ($fileHandle, $offset, 0);

            if ($chunkSize > $size) {
                $chunkSize = $size;
            }
            elsif (($chunkSize + $offset) > $size) {
                $chunkSize = $size - $offset;
            }

            my $length = read($fileHandle, $chunk, $chunkSize); 
            say STDERR "Chunk size for $i: " . $chunkSize . "(" . ($chunkSize + $offset) . "/$size) starting at " . $offset .": ";

            $output{ $i } = $chunk;
        }
    });
}

$_->join for @threads;
close($fileHandle); 

open(my $fileHandle, '>', $file . '.comp') or die("Error reading file, stopped");
binmode($fileHandle);

for (1...$parts) {
    print "Reassembling part $_...";
    print $fileHandle $output{ $_ };
}

close ($fileHandle);
```

If I run that code on this simple text file, it works:

```
1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Result of md5sum on both source and destination file:

```
6d8d0b2c6a06f88e13167fffacb1b74e  /home/tbutler/text.txt
6d8d0b2c6a06f88e13167fffacb1b74e  /home/tbutler/text.txt.comp
```

But, if I take a 9 GB tarball (and increase the chunk size to 500 MB by changing the appropriate line to `my $chunkSize = 500 * 1024 * 1024`) and run it likewise, the md5sum result is not matching. In fact the resultant file is approximately a gigabyte smaller than the original file and I can't figure out why.

Comment: So digging some more, is the problem that I'm sharing a file handle between threads? If I quit sharing it and open one per thread, it seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Is `0` an element on the queue? Then what happens to the thread that calls `while (my $i=queue->dequeue_nb) ...` when `0` is at the front of the queue?

Comment: If multiple threads are using the same file handle, you probably want [pread() and pwrite()](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::ReplaceBytes) instead of normal io functions.